# How to repair a XFS filesystem with a dirty log?

Tags: filesystems, logging, repair, filesystem-corruption, xfs

I had a server crash while its RAID array was running in a degraded state and now the XFS file system is corrupted.  I have read up on how to repair the filesystem but most things I have tried have failed.  I have determined that the log is dirty by

> sudo xfs_logprint -t /dev/mapper/scientific-data4
> xfs_logprint:
> data device: 0xfd06
> log device: 0xfd06 daddr: 68719476512 length: 4173824
> log tail: 65469 head: 77525 state: 
> xfs_logprint: failed in xfs_do_recovery_pass, error: 117

I tried to dump the metadata and experiment with repairing that, but xfs_metadump also fails

> sudo xfs_metadump /dev/mapper/scientific-data4 data4.metadump
> Metadata CRC error detected at 0x557dce319bee, xfs_agf block 0x6ffffff91/0x200
> xfs_metadump: cannot init perag data (74). Continuing anyway.
> xfs_metadump: cannot create dump file

I tried to mount the filesystem read-only, but this also fails

> sudo mount /dev/mapper/scientific-data4 /data4 -t xfs -o ro,norecovery
> mount: /data4: mount(2) system call failed: Structure needs cleaning.

I know that I can do xfs_repair -L but I am worried about losing data.  Is there anything else I can try.

Incidentally, I used RAID recovery software to copy many files off of the array.  Surprisingly, the software gave me no complaints regarding the filesystem and I was able to read files wherever I tried.

Comment: use overlay or snapshot or full copy for potentially dangerous experiments, for example https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Recovering_a_failed_software_RAID#Making_the_harddisks_read-only_using_an_overlay_file

Comment: Thanks for the tip - I was not aware of this trick.  Unfortunately this is a hardware RAID system and the disks are hidden behind the controller.  I don't think I can access the disks individually, at least not simply by /dev/sda etc.